# Incorrect Backend Url from getUrl() method

Tags: magento2, product-urls

I am trying to write link to Payment Transaction to Oder's comment.

But it seems UrlBuilder generates incorrect security key for the link.

**Link from transaction page:**

> backend/sales/transactions/view/txn_id/4/key/107dd581bc9af9c35f8069181a5ebe7195c9cc3d96936201fb9a4a53b4960dd9/

**Link from comment:**

> backend/sales/transactions/view/txn_id/4/key/3711f2bda03d84cfc34662e93697d94ac73b27061e2c1144cd7edd32e88adddc/

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
 ...
) {
    $this->urlBuilder        = $urlBuilder;
...
}


$this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
    'sales/transactions/view',
    [
        'txn_id' => $txnId
    ]
);
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try with `$this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
    '*/*/*',
    [
        'txn_id' => $txnId
    ]
);`

Comment: @kunj  `\*/*/*\`  is not ok. I'm doing it from custom controller.